# Wait until HTTP call will end before sending a new http call from multiple observables - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have multiple observables that are basically listen to form-fields changes and each time the field value is changing, it's calling the API

My problem is that I've to wait until the ongoing api call is ended and only then perform another call.

The current implementation looks like this :

```
obs1$.pipe(
(tap(val) => callApi())
)

obs2$.pipe(
(tap(val) => callApi())
)

obs3$.pipe(
(tap(val) => callApi())
)

callApi() {
  this.http.post(url, someValue) <=== wait until this end
}
```

I've tried so many things but I just can't get it to work, any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap

Comment: @ritaj Thanks for you replay, concatMap not working here, in my case it's not waiting until the req is finished to fire th next one

Comment: "Because concatMap does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes..."

Comment: The thing is that I'm using multiple observables that are using the 'callApi' method and not one, if the idea to do something like this:
```
 obs3$.pipe(
(concatMap(val) => callApi())
)

 obs2$.pipe(
(concatMap(val) => callApi())
)
...
```

It's not working..

Comment: `combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$).pipe(concatMap(val) => callApi())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a combination of `combineLatest` and `concatMap`

```
combineLatest([obs1$, obs2$, obs3#])
    .pipe(
        concatMap(([v1,v2,v3]) => callApi())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have only one API call in progress at a time, then I think you can solve your problem with the following:

```
merge(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$)
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => callApi()),
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

First merge your source observables into a single stream.

Then `exhaustMap` will ignore further values from your merged source observable until the observable returned from `callApi()` completes.

Comment: Why `exhaustMap` and not `concatMap` or `mergeMap`? With `exhaustMap` you run the risk of not eaecuting a call to the API if the previous one has not yet completed.

Comment: @Picci The question states that they want to wait for an API call to completes before another one is triggered, so `exhaustMap` should work well here.

Comment: `exhaustMap` will execute the next call only IF the previous one is completed. Which means that if the previous one is still on fly, the next one will be skipped. To obtain the desired behavior I think that `concatMap` it the operator to use.

Comment: @Picci I believe that the desired behaviour is to only have one API call in progress at a time. In the question code, the `callApi()` calls do not rely on values from the source observables.